# How to sort strings alphabetically (without using LINQ)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to order some strings alphabetically in C#. I have found what I consider to be inconsistent behaviour.

I've seached on the internet but found only the most basic of exmaples which implement the code I had already created.

```cs
List<string> a = new List<string> { "a", "W", "w"};
List<string> b = new List<string> { "Waw", "wWa", "awW" };

a.Sort();
b.Sort();
```

So after the sort I have:

```
a = { "a", "w", "W" }
b = { "awW", "Waw", "wWa" }
```

Which seems inconsistent.

> The sort of `a` has put `w` before `W`
>
> The sort of `b` has put `W` before `w`

If .NET is comparing by using hascodes maybe that could explain this. How can I get a consistent result?

Comment: "The sort of b has put W before w" - No, it's put "Wa" before "wW". This is consistent with case insensitive sorting. See [String.Compare Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8) for more info

Comment: It doesn't seem inconsistent to me. It's a case-sensitive sort. You want [the Sort() overload that takes a `Comparison<String>` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8). You can then specify that you want the sort to be case-blind.

Comment: Not sure if this could help you? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a788b262-17c4-44f2-a9dd-f4c493653f40/how-do-i-sort-a-liststring-without-using-a-lambda-expression?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonses. It seems to me that as list a is ordered as "a","w","W" that .NET has declared that "w" comes before "W". OK. So I would have thought that "wWa" should come before "Waw". I tried passing arguments CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, InvariantCultureIgnoreCasea and OrdinalIgnoreCase but no difference.

Comment: typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the behaviour I want by using StringComparer.Ordinal